# Using Python Openpyxl to wrap text

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I am just trying to wrap text of a excel file. The first row has long text values. I am getting an error when doing this.

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

os.chdir("C:/Pathto/TheFile/Here")
wb = Workbook('Output.xlsx')
ws = wb.active # wb.active returns a Worksheet object

ws['B1':'X1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

wb.save('Output.xlsx')
```

The error is from the line `ws['B1':'X1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)` I get the same error with `ws['B1']...`

If you are interested the error message is:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Pythonfile...\test.py", line 9, in 
ws['B1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: You have to style every cell in the range individually.

Comment: Charlie, I get the same error when I just use 'B1'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is what I changed the line to: `ws['B1'].alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)` . The problem is I still get the same error of _"Traceback ... 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"_.

Comment: Check what `ws` is. According to the traceback, it's `None`